# Getting value error while performing iteration loop on dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, iteration

I am running the following code:

```
 def backwash (df):
    df.loc[0, 'backwash'] = np.NaN
     for i in range (3, len(df)-2):
         while (df.loc[i,'MF1 Permeate Flow (m3/min)']==0):
            if (df.loc[i-2:i+2, 'MF1 Trans-Membrane Pressure (kPa) (PDI3423)']>0):
                 df.loc[i,'backwash'] = 'BW'
                 break
            else:
                break
        else:
            pass
    return df
```

The problem is with `df.loc [i-2:i+2, 'MF1 Trans-Membrane Pressure (kPa) (PDI3423)']`. Hence I get the Value error (the truth value is ambiguous). Is there any other way to run this loop?

I essentially want to check the value on certain row based on the value of previous and following two rows.

Comment: would be great to provide an example input and the matching expected output

Comment: You cannot compare a Series of booleans to a unique boolean, you need: `if all(df.loc[i-2:i+2, 'MF1 Trans-Membrane Pressure (kPa) (PDI3423)']>0)` to check if all values are True or `any` if only one True matters

Comment: ** got automatically while trying to bold it here. That's not the part of code.

Comment: ok, you cannot format code, I fixed it